# human verification without known solution

Tags: artificial-intelligence, captcha

Can anyone think of a human verification challenge which:

1. computers can generate
2. computers can verify the solution
3. humans are best at finding the solution

CAPTCHAs wouldn't satisfy this criteria because a computer must know the solution prior to verifying.

Answer (score 2):

Tasks relying on [visual pop out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_search) can be verifyable by computer, computationally expensive, but instantly solvable by people.

Mathematical proofs are another area where humans can outperform computers by a large margin.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer must be short (probably a good idea for captcha) *and*, as you stated, a solution can be verified by the computer then with an exhaustive enumeration+verification cycle the computer can solve the problem.

I suspect there's no way to do this even if the answer can be large.

Comment: Actually, computers (with good algorithms, not brute force) are better than humans to find a solution most of the time. For example: place 64 queens on a 64*64 chessboard without any 2 can attack each other. This takes seconds for a computer, while some human's couldn't do this in 10 minutes if their life dependend on it.